# What software is needed to develop a flash game?

Tags: flash, adobe

I want to make a free game with flash.

Several month ago, I created a free game with html5 canvas.
But unfortunately, most of people who access the page of the game use old version IEs and they can not play the html5 canvas game.
So I want make flash version of it.

Can I use `Flash builder` to create flash game?
Or I have to buy `Flash professional`?
Or are there other good softwares?

I hope I could create flash games with Flash builder,
because Flash pro is much more expensive than Flash builder.

If I have to buy Flash pro, I'll buy it.
But is it normal to pay more than 600 dollars for developing a free game?
There are a lot of free flash games on the Internet.
Did their developers pay 600 dollars to create their free games?

Comment: Developers of free games usually recover costs by selling ad space or also having a "paid" version of the game.
Meanwhile, advise your users to switch to the standards-compliant and latest Firefox 5.0 for html5 support

Comment: Really? You think people will install a different browser just to play a free web game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this topic has been already discussed many times.

E.g. here: [What IDE can be used for ActionScript 3 coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385169/best-ide-for-actionscript-3-coding)

Comment: Thank you for your information. The page means FDT and Flash Builder can be used to develop flash games?(I use mac OS X.)
FDT has 3 editions. I dont know which one is better for game developing.

Comment: Since FDT has debugger only in Max edition (according to http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/features/), this one is better. Actually, I don't know, how to develop without debugger.

Comment: Max edition($700) is too expensive for me to buy. I'm gonna try flash builder. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Flash Professional IDE is organized more for people who like to animate on the Flash timeline.  Flash Builder is organized better for people who prefer to build through code.  Everyone has their own preference.

There are no alternatives that I am aware of to the Flash Professional IDE.

There are alternatives to Flash Builder, however. Flash Develop is the only free one that I am aware of.

Comment: Your answer means flash bulder is more suitable for developing game than flash pro? And flash pro is suitable for just making animation or movie?
Can i create a game without `animation on the flash time line`?

Comment: You can code games using the Flash Professional IDE.  It can do it.  But it is going to be more focused on animation timelines than code.  You don't get very good code hints through Flash Professional IDE.  You don't get refactoring support.  You don't get debugging.

Flash Builder has code hints.  It has refactoring support.  It has debugging.  But there's no timeline to easily animate in.  Most people do their animations in Flash Professional, and them import them into Flash Builder via SWC libraries, and handle code in Flash Builder.  Uses each tool for their strengths.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Professional (which costs a bomb)
Flash Builder 4 (free version available for students)
FlashDevelop (light and free IDE)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You mean all of them can be used for developing game? In game development, Flash Professional have no advantages over Flash Builder?

Comment: Flash Professional (FP) is MUCH better than Flash Builder (FB) for grahics.  
By this, I mean that Flash Builder is sort of like Visual Studio (easy to build a gui, etc). Also, FB has MUCH a better debugger and coding interface, but you can not create drawings in FB like you can do in FP

Answer (score 1):

Flash Professional is used to make animations using vector graphics. It is very good at that, but if you don't need that then you don't need Flash Professional. What you need to compile ActionScript code into a .swf is the free Flex SDK. Flash Builder is a good IDE you can use to write the code, or you can use the free Flash Develop. The IDE I use at work is FDT; that has great debugging tools but is very expensive.